# Server Side Process For Windows Notification

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently working on online booking system which takes all the details from the user and saves it into the database.

Here is code for that

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (customerid, pname,cnumber, paddress, daddress, via, pdate, hours, mins, luggage, vtype, pnum, info) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
      $statement->bind_param('issssssiiisis', $user_id, $pname, $number, $pickupaddress, $dropaddress, $via, $date, $hours, $minutes, $luggages, $vtype, $passengers, $additional);

      if($statement->execute()){
            $_SESSION['message'] = "1";
            header('Location: activebookings.php');
        }
      else{
      die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
      }
      $statement->close();
      }
```

And then on the backend side of web application i have a this page where site admin sees the bookings and process them here is code for that

```
<?php 
     while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults)) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Date/time"><?php echo $product['pdate'].' / '. $product['hours'].':'. $product['mins']; ?></td>
      <td data-label="Pick up address"><?php echo $product['paddress']; ?></td>
      <td data-label="Dropoff address"><?php echo $product['daddress']; ?></td>
      <td data-label="Job Details"><a href="viewjob.php?view=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
        <button id="DIV_1">View Details</button>
        </a></td>
      <td data-label="Confirm Booking"><a href="controllers.php?confirm=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
        <button id="DIV_1">Confirm This Booking</button>
        </a></td>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Cancel Booking"><a href="controllers.php?cancel=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
        <button id="DIV_1"style="background: #F44336 none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;"">Cancel This Booking</button>
        </a></td>
    </tr>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Now what i want is some sort of server-side processing or ajax or constant connection between two pages to triggers windows HTML 5 Notification when user submit the booking form a site admin gets the notification

Answer (score 0):

If the admin has a page on the site open in a browser, he/she can receive the notification. To generate the notification, the page could use AJAX to poll the server for new events (using the timestamp of the most recent event as a filter) or use web-sockets to have the server "push" notification data to the page. Getting the info from the server is the hard part, displaying the notification is the easy part. See https://davidwalsh.name/notifications-api for example code to display the notification. Since the admin user will have a page displayed, you could also just display the new data (if appropriate for the page displayed).

Comment: Hey thanks for that, Is this still gonna work if admin logged in and has a page open on other computer ?

Comment: It will work on any page that contains the code to check with the server and emit the notification. In your admin template or base code, you would need to decide to include the JS code for this based on the user's permissions/login/etc. That way, any Admin will see the notifications on any page.

Comment: Thank You. I'll give it a shot, You're are a star